Plumbing: hot water in cold pipes - water heater problem?
We recently moved into a new apartment that has its own water heater. We have been experiencing random bouts of very hot water coming out of all cold taps in the home, that will only go away after running the taps for a while and letting all the hot water out. In the mean time, the hot taps would be cold. (Pretty sure the pipes are not connected backwards as the cold and hot are normal other than these brief bouts)
We read online that a common cause is faucet cartridge issues, but most of these occurances were in the morning when no one was using any faucet for the whole night.
So right now our prime suspect is the water heater. Either the pressure is too high, or the thermostat might be faulty. Before we call in someone to take a look at it, can we do any further detective work to isolate the issue?

First check that the pipes are connected correctly - sounds like the hot's in the cold and the cold's in the hot. "Faucet cartridge issues" don't require the faucet to be in use - it's from the anti-scald part and that's not dependent on the faucet being in use.

See also: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/271092/18078

@Ecnerwal Thanks for the info, we'll look deeper into how faucet cartriges work

Are the plumbing pipes in a garage or attic or ran under the house?

@DMoore it's a two-level apartment, the heater is in the lower level

sounds like your faucets are marked incorrectly

Where in the country are you?  What you describe would be common in Arizona but decidedly weird in Minnesota.  What kind of water heater do you have?  Is it all the faucets or only certain ones? Pictures of the water heater and faucet pipes might help.

@mdfst13 I'm located in British Columbia, Canada. There doesn't seem to be any recirculation system connected to the water heater, only one cold pipe and one hot pipe connected to it


Before we call in someone to take a look at it, can we do any further detective work to isolate the issue?

Check if you have a recirculation system.  Some of those put hot water in the cold pipes.  This would normally appear with a tankless hot water heater.
There is no requirement that bad faucet cartridges be used in order to fail.
